# How to write a conditional promise.resolve properly in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, async-await, promise

I have a project in react native using typescript and I would like to use `Promise.resolve().then()` of an object with a condition which causing a type error in typescript. Below is the situation:

I have the first object (as sample):

```
const objectA = async () => {
  // get the object from local storage
  const user = await asyncStorage.getItem(userAKey)

  return {
    // types are all in string
    id: user?.id || '',
    email: user?.email || '',
  }
}
```

And I have my second object (as sample):

```
const objectB = async () => {
  // get the object from local storage
  const user = await asyncStorage.getItem(userBKey)

  return {
    // types are all in string
    id: user?.id || '',
    email: user?.email || '',
    organisation: user?.organisation || ''
  }
}
```

So both objects have different types and keys with value. Here is the problem, I have a condition to check which object to be resolve based on some host type:

```
const objectTobeResolved = type === 'primary' ? objectA : objectB
```

So based on that condition, I pass it to the Promise:

```
const userData = () => {
   Promise.resolve(objectTobeResolved).then((values) => { ... })
}
```

I will get the type error here in the typescript for `objectTobeResolved`.
Basically the type error here is mentioning something like `objectA | objectB`, but I actually only need to pass one of the object based on the condition above and I don't need the `objectA | objectB` condition as it is only either `objectA` or `objectB` based on the declared host type I had in the app launcher.

I don't quite understand how to declare it properly in typescript since I have just learned to use Typescript.

What is a right way to write the promise here? should I use `race` or `all` instead? But I only need to check one object at a time. Or should I declare or initialise in a certain way? Or maybe I don't even need to use `promise` at all?

Edit: I have updated the codes above to my real case scenario.
The codes are actually running correctly, just that the type error keep showing up and I couldn't pass the test. A shortcut is to use //@ts-ignore, but since our practice is to not ignore the warning, so I'm trying to find a correct way to write it without having a warning which causing the test to be failed.

Comment: Looks like your type hinting is wrong. Can you post the line where it is defined as well?

Comment: First of all, you should really consider why you want to do that. Unless you have a very specific need, `Promise.resolve(value).then((value) => {})` is equivalent to just using the `value` directly. 

Second, there should be something else happening in the code we cannot see as the code you wrote works and compiles perfectly in TS

Comment: This is a decent question, but we do need whole example of the code.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with the full code. It's currently not clear where the condition is evaluated and where the function that calls `then` is defined.

Comment: Both `objectA` and `objectB` are promise returning functions so would expect something like `(type === 'primary' ? objectA() : objectB()).then(values => ...)`.

Answer (score -1):

More code would be helpful, but I think what you may be asking about is how to create a  union type so you can effectively refer to your result being a this or that. If so, maybe you could use something like this? I believe you could state it a number of other ways too, but I just wanted to illustrate the point.

```
const objectA = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
}

const objectB = {
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5,
}

interface ABtype {
    a: Number
    b: Number
}

interface CDEtype {
    c: Number
    d: Number
    e: Number
}

interface ABpromiseType extends Promise<ABtype> {
}

interface CDEpromiseType extends Promise<CDEtype> {
}

interface ABCDEunionTypeCombined extends Promise<CDEtype | ABtype> {
}

// Something randomly true or false.
let conditionalCheck = new Date().getTime() % 2 == 0;

const someFunction = () => {
    const objectTobeResolved : ABCDEunionTypeCombined  = (conditionalCheck ? Promise.resolve(objectA) : Promise.resolve(objectB) );
}
```